# Keras/Tensorflow: Train multiple models on the same GPU in a loop or using Process

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory

I have multiple models to train in Keras/Tensorflow at a stretch one after the other without manually calling `train.py`, so I did:

```
for i in range(0, max_count):
    model = get_model(i)   # returns ith model
    model.fit(...)
    model.save(...)
```

It runs fine for the `i=0` (and in fact runs perfectly when run separately). The problem is that when the second time model is loaded, i get `ResourceExhaustedError OOM`, so I tried to release memory at the end of for loop

```
del model
keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.clear_session()
tf.reset_default_graph()
gc.collect()
```

none of which individually or collectively works.

I looked up further and found that the only way to release GPU memory is to end the process.

Also rom this keras [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5345)

> Update (2018/08/01): Currently only TensorFlow
>   backend supports proper cleaning up of the session. This can be done
>   by calling K.clear_session(). This will remove EVERYTHING from memory
>   (models, optimizer objects and anything that has tensors internally).
>   So there is no way to remove a specific stale model. This is not a bug
>   of Keras but a limitation of the backends.

So clearly the way to go is to create a process everytime I load a model and wait for it to end and then create another one in a fresh process like here:

```
import multitasking
def train_model_in_new_process(model_module, kfold_object, x, y, x_test, y_test, epochs, model_file_count):
    training_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=train_model, args=(x, y, x_test, y_test, epochs, model_file_count, ))
    training_process.start()
    training_process.join()
```

but then it throws this error:

```
  File "train.py", line 110, in train_model_in_new_process
    training_process.start()
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I really can't utilize the information presented in the error to see what I was doing wrong. It is clearly pointing at the line `training_process.start()`, but I can't seem to understand what's causing the problem.

Any help to train models either using `for` loop or using `Process` is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `Multiprocessing` doesn't like `modules` or more precisely `importlib` modules. I was loading models from numbered `.py` files using `importlib`

```
model_module = importlib.import_module(model_file)
```

and hence the trouble.

I did the same inside the `Process` and it was all fine :)

But I still could NOT find a way to do this without `Process`es, using `for`s. If you have an answer, please post it here, you're welcome. But anyway, I'm continuing with processes, because processes are, I believe, cleaner in a way that they are isolated and clears all the memory allocated for that specific one when done.